# .net Maui camera throwing error about write external storage

Tags: c#, maui

Anyone worked out how to take a photo in Maui on android api 31 using MediaPicker?

Lots of people getting the same error as this but I haven’t found a solution yet. I believe this version of Android doesn’t have the same permissions and so MediaPicker doesn’t seem to work with it. As soon as I call the camera I get the following:

Error: Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.PermissionException: 'StorageWrite permission was not granted: Denied'

Android.Manifest entries:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />

    <!-- Required to maintain app compatibility. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Code:

```
    private async void TakePhotoPressed()
    {
        MediaPickerOptions options = new MediaPickerOptions();
        options.Title = "Add Attachment";
       
        FileResult result = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync(options);
...
}
```

Note that if I don't request StorageWrite permission I get the following error:

Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.PermissionException: 'You need to declare using the permission: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your AndroidManifest.xml'

So, bit of a catch 22 situation...

Thanks

Comment: Please post the relevant code and the **specific** error message

Comment: What API version does your app specify as TARGET? Long discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11275). Short answer: unless you require features of latest Android API, set a LOWER API as the target. That discussion mentions various permissions of Android 12 and 13; worth reading and comparing to yours. I didn't read the last few comments of issue to see if there is a fix coming soon for current API.

Comment: I am just targetting net7.0-android. In fact I raised an issue with the Maui team and they said the problem has been fixed, so I assume we will get it working in the next release.